# SQL Server: dump/export database indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-indexes

I got a SQL Server database which I would like to dump, but only indexes and maybe structure, but I couldn't figure it out how.

I use SQL Server Management Studio, but I cant see how would I do this. MySQL is much more easier then this :)

Any tips or how-to's would help.

NOTE: I'm new to SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

Right click database ->click on generate scripts --->Choose  Script Entire  database

In new window,click on Advanced  and choose types of data to script as Schema only ..you can play with another options

now complete all the screens  and you can see structure of all tables and indexes..

[image]

Comment: Thanks!, will try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

To export the indexes, together with the table schemas, do these steps:

1. Right-click the database and choose to generate scripts.

   [image]
2. In the wizard on the page *Set Scripting Options*, click *Advanced*.

   [image]
3. Set *Script Indexes* to *True*.

   [image]
4. Click OK, complete the wizard, and you should now see the table schema SQL together with the indexes.